# UIButton accessibilityLabel on selection?

Tags: ios, uibutton, accessibility, uiaccessibility

Simple one: is there a way to get a `UIButton` to read a specific accessibility message after it has been pushed? It’s a toggle, it has a label/hint for before it’s pushed, but after the user interacts with it, I’d like it to audibly confirm that it was toggled, and convey whether it was just switched on or off.

Is there some kind of selection hint or similar that I can use to read something AFTER the user interacts with the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overlooking for a moment that VoiceOver will announce the new state of most correctly implemented custom controls, you're looking for [`UIAccessibilityPostNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uikitfunctionreference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIAccessibilityPostNotification).